# RNN LSTM input conflict due to generator

Tags: classification, keras

I am trying to do text classification with LSTM RNN on 255 length padded sequences.

My classification data looks like this

```
1, 'sequence 1'
```

The first column is the class label for the sequence. Since I am using custom word embedding (100 dims) I have created a custom data generator and used [fit_generator](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator) api.

My data is converted into following format after preprocessing

> X -> (batch_size, time_steps=255, 100) # 100 dim word embeddings
>
> Y -> (batch_size, 2) # 2 for binary class labels

Following is what I have tried with custom generator

```
def data_generator(file):
    while True:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                # Get embedded line encodes each sequence to its constituent word vectors
                # creates a 2D np array of size (max_len, 100)
                yield get_embedded_line(row[1]), to_categorical(row[0], num_classes=2)


input_layer = Input(shape=(255, 100))
lstm1 = LSTM(100, return_sequences=True)(input_layer)
dense1 = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(lstm1)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=dense1)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(data_generator('data.csv'), steps_per_epoch=10)
```

The model defined above is not even compiling, it throws following error

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 1)

Answer (score 0):

**get_embedded_line(row[1])** has to return a matrix with size (Batch size, 255, 100) but it is yeilding (100, 1) matrix. please check the implementation of "get_embedded_line" function.